# Trying to implement the QuickSort on python : NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, quicksort

I'm learning to use Python, and to start I'm coding some sorts.
I tried one hundred possible changes, but I don't know how to fix it.
Here's my code:

```
from random import *
from time import *

L = []
for m in range(0,100):
    L.append(randint(0,100))

def quicksort(L, first, last):

    i = first
    j = last
    pivote = (L[i] + L[j]) / 2

    while i < j:
        while L[i] < pivote:
            i+=1
        while L[j] > pivote:
            j-=1
        if i <= j:
            x == L[j]
            L[j] == L[i]
            L[i] == x
            i+=1
            j-=1

    if first < j:
        L == quicksort(L, first, j)
    if last > i:
        L == quicksort(L, i, last)

    return L

start = time() 
print ("Disordered:" , L)
L = quicksort(L, L[0], L[len(L)-1])
print ("Ordered:" ,L)
print ("%.2f seconds" % (time() - start))
```

AND this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ricardo/Desktop/QuickSortR.py", line 48, in <module>
    L = quicksort(L, L[0], L[len(L)-1])
  File "/Users/Ricardo/Desktop/QuickSortR.py", line 28, in quicksort
    x == L[j]
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you wanted to *assign to* `x`:

```
x = L[j]
```

You are using `==`; a comparison, instead. You do this in several places; `==` evaluates to a boolean value (when the two items are considered equal), while `=` assigns to a variable.

In python, you can swap variables directly without a temporary:

```
if i <= j:
    L[j], L[i] = L[i], L[j]
```

Answer (score 2):

In several places you are using `==` instead of `=` in assignment, like `x == L[j]`, this is how you compare to items.  To assign to `x` you should have `x = L[j]`.

Note that there are several other lines like this that you will need to fix as well.

Comment: @RicardoMoctezumaS You should accept one of these answers (the big check box on the left).